# The IListSource does not contain any data sources.?

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have this code when run it i get this error
 The IListSource does not contain any data sources. 
 i try more but no benefit ..

```
    public static DataSet SelectAll_EmployeeType()
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    string sqlCommand = "";
    SNS_Lib.SQL_DB mySQL = new SNS_Lib.SQL_DB();
    sqlCommand = "SELECT * FROM EmployeeType";
    ds = mySQL.SelectFromQuery(sqlCommand);
    return ds;

}
private void FillSource()
{ 
        DataSet ds = Client.SelectAll_EmployeeType();
        DDL_UserType.DataSource = ds;
        DDL_UserType.DataTextField = "Type";
       DDL_UserType.DataValueField = "Type";                             
        DDL_UserType.DataBind();
        DDL_UserType.Items.Insert(0, "-- Select One");
   }
```

when run this application i have this error

```
 The IListSource does not contain any data sources.
```

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: The IListSource does not contain any data sources.

Source Error:

```
Line 224://ds.Tables[0].DefaultView
```

Line 225:            DDL_UserType.DataValueField = "Type"
Line 226:            DDL_UserType.DataBind()
Line 227:
Line 228:            //Add the item at the first position.

Comment: error in this line . Line 226: DDL_UserType.DataBind() ;

Comment: well: what is `ds.Tables.Count` ? also: **why oh why do people use `DataTable` for this stuff?**; ok, the second of those was rhetorical - you don't need to answer that; just the first one; btw - the `= new DataSet()` is unnecessary and wasteful, since that is discarded in the `ds = ...` line at the end; you might as well remove `ds` from `SelectAll_EmployeeType()` and just `return mySQL.SelectFromQuery(sqlCommand);`